How would a record of a misdemeanor traffic violation affect post-Ph.D job prospects?
I was clocked going 21 MPH over the posted speed limit on a 65 MPH highway when I wasn't paying attention and was cited by the police. The police thankfully only cited me for going 5 MPH over the limit. However, suppose the citation is upgraded to a misdemeanor traffic violation.
Could such a citation on my record affect my job prospects?
Could such a record prevent me from receiving my Ph.D?
Edit: Since I was cited for going 5 MPH over the limit, I paid the $150 USD fine and don't need to appear in court either since I'm not fighting it. We're good.

I'm guessing you're unlikely to face serious consequences. Be polite, apologize for having broken the speed limit, don't complain or argue, pay the fine if one is required of you, and avoid doing this again -- and I'd be very surprised if you were charged with a crime. You might have to pay increased insurance rates, but I'm guessing that most people (including professors) have gotten a speeding ticket at some time or other. Best wishes to you.

This question doesn’t look like you need academic advice - your error is not uncommon, unrelated to academia, you already got lucky how things are developing, but for some reason you have made at least three pessimistic leaps of mind to construct you into the worst possible outcome. Why exactly do you think this will affect your academic career in any significant way?

I've edited the question to take much of the emotion out of the question. Hopefully this will make it more useful to future visitors. Admittedly some of the context of the answers is lost, so feel free to roll back if it's too much.

Misdemeanor's unrelated to academia are unlikely to affect you, or even be noticed. Felonies likely could.
OTOH, you will be judged in the job market by individuals and few, if any, can predict what everyone would do or think. But the risk seems small.

Seems unlikely that any future employer would ask about traffic tickets. Even for security clearances moving violations under a specific dollar limit are not an issue.

@JonCuster It's plausible an employer might care about it if they're applying for a job as a professional driver (e.g. delivery or taxi driver), but I don't think you're likely to find those sorts of jobs coming up in academia.

Relax
This started out as a response to a comment, but:  Relax.  Take a deep breath.  Let it out.  Relax.
Even for jobs requiring security clearances in the United States (which involve stringent background checks) misdemeanors are unlikely to be a cause for rejection.   There are a handful of misdemeanors that would be, but the most likely to obtain in this circumstance would be speeding because you had been drinking which, per your question, is not the case.
Misdemeanors won't do you any favors, but other than those narrow exceptions, they are not show-stoppers.
I realize you're not asking about Clearance jobs, but because those are widely understood to have strict background checks, they serve as a useful basis for comparison.
You can never tell what crazy hijinx a private sector company will get up to if they have a lunatic in HR, but you don't want to work for a company like that anyway.  This is not something I would lose sleep over.
As for your degree, I would be both shocked and outraged if the topic ever came up.  It's not the university's job to watch your driving record.

Agree that an isolated misdemeanor speeding offence is unlikely to cause rejection for a clearance. However, if it were part of a history of incidents that could give the impression of a risk-taking/thrill-seeking personality, that could be more of an issue.

If you were issued a citation for 5 mph over the limit, it is very unlikely that will change.  Only you and the officer know what your actual speed was, and the officer is unlikely to say, "I gave him a break, but I've changed my mind."
My guess: you will be asked to pay a fine.  Pay it.  Don't say anything to anyone about how fast you were actually going.  Um, unless you are asked while under oath.
In some states, including mine (Georgia), speeding, no matter how little, is a misdemeanor.  Even so, your school and future employers are likely to consider this a "traffic ticket" if they find out about it at all.  If asked, say, "I was cited for going 5 mph over the speed limit."  Do not further discuss the circumstances.
Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer and this isn't legal advice; it's common sense.
This question will likely be closed because it's off-topic, but I hope I've helped you calm down a bit.

Yes, you've helped quite a bit. Thank you.
